# Group by the records and that particular group if condition matched then set final result like below

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
declare @table table
(
    id int,
    status varchar(50)
)

insert into @table
    values(1,'Open'),(1,'Open'),(1,'Open'),
    (2,'Open'),(2,'Pending'),(2,'Open'),
    (3,'Open'),(3,'Completed'),(3,'Pending'),
    (4,'Pending'),(4,'Pending'),(4,'Pending'),
    (5,'Completed'),(5,'Completed'),(5,'Completed')
```

I want to group by the records and that particular group if the condition matched then set final result like below

```
--expected output
--Id    Status
--1     Open
--2     Pending
--3     Pending
--4     Pending
--5     Completed
```

For each group, I want to check the following condition

```
--Open
--Open => Open
--Open

--Open
--Pending => Pending
--Open

--Open
--Completed => Pending
--Open

--Pending
--Pending =>Pending
--Pending

--Completed
--Completed =>Completed
--Completed
```

Comment: Please explain the logic.  It is not obvious that you have all conditions covered.

Comment: One assumes you are only using 1 version of SQL Server, so please correct your tags. And quote formatting is for when you are actually quoting something, not just for emphasis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional logic:

```
select id,
       (case when max(status) = min(status) then max(status)
             else 'Pending'
        end) as status 
from @table t
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc47d05b03b0ff2d4c9f21c8134acfab) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon Linoff I tried but I could not get any idea how it can be done

Comment: at least with your solution, I have an idea of how it can be achieved